# Nanoc - Skip file during compile/autocompile

Tags: ruby, erb, nanoc

I'm building a site with Nanoc and have one file (with it's own layout file) that reads all other files metadata, does some magic and saves the file. Unfortunately, this process takes a long time and developing other views with autocompile is taking ages. Is it possible to add some files to ignore list that won't be enqueued to compilation (and during compilation to production remove them from ignores)? Or are there other methods to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, nanoc will always read all data from your contents directory. You can remove files from further processing by implementing a `preprocess` method which removes some generated `items` entries... e.g. in `Rules`:

```
preprocess do
  skip_unimportant_items
end
```

In a .rb file in lib/:

```
def skip_unimportant_items
  @items.delete_if { |i| !i[:important] }
end
```

This will remove all items which have no `important` element (or the element set to false) in their respective metadata.

Comment: Ah, brilliant. Why did I not notice this earlier?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the Nanoc Doc recommendation:

```
ignore '/assets/layouts/your_files/*/'
```

http://nanoc.ws/doc/rules/